# Get String of Today's Date in mm-dd-yy format (in VB.net)

Tags: string, vb.net

I am trying to create a string of today's date in VB.net and this is the code I am trying:

```
Dim strtest As String
strtest = CStr(DatePart("mm", Date.Today) & "-" & CStr(DatePart("dd", Date.Today)) _ 
& "-" & CStr(DatePart("yy", Date.Today)))
```

however, I am receiving the following error, "Argument 'Interval is not a valid value"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yy")` See [Standard date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: Or in Basic syntax rather than .NET `MsgBox(Format(Now(), "MM-dd-yy"))`

Comment: Both of the above call the same library function. One is .NET specific and works in C# as well. Mine is in BASIC.  Microsoft is sabotaging the BASIC language by turning it into C# because when they were kids they thought it was uncool.

Comment: C was about how CPUs did stuff and considered low level. BASIC is the same as algebra that you learn on the blackboard and so is high level. Anyone who studied maths at school can understand BASIC. C++ and C# are forcing solutions to server type application problems onto programs for ordinary people (not servers).